# ASP.NET MVC - Display Result of Serverside Process

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to MVC, and just building my first site, using NerdDinner as an example. I'm wondering what is the best approach to displaying the result of a server-side process. eg on a screen where a user is asked to change their password - if the change fails validation then error messages are displayed as per NerdDinner pattern using the current view. If the change succeeds, ideally I want to stay on the same page, hide the change password controls and just display a "password change succeeded" message.

The options seem to be to either, redirect to a new view with the success message, or have hidden controls on the view and show/hide them using values returned in the ViewData. Is there another more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just do it like this:

```
<% if (ViewData["success"] != null)
{ %>
<div class="success">Huge Success!</div>
<% }
else
{ %>
```

Such things belong to the View, so you really shouldn't be thinking too hard about how to get it pretty. It's pretty by design, because it's in your view.

Comment: Thanks - it's like going back to classic ASP mindset - quite hard after years of ASP.NET webforms!

Comment: A bit, yes, but since there is no logic it's all good, think about it as xslt.